# VSCodeのclang-formatについて、空白行が１行しかできません。

Tags: vscode

VSCodeの標準のフォーマッタを利用しています。(C/C++ Extention?）
空白の改行を２行入れたいのですが、１行しか入れることができません。
あまり関係ないと思いますが、言語はC言語です。
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep という設定で本来は設定出来るらしいのですが、上手くいきません。
設定内容にエラーは出ていないです。(vscodeの出力欄になにも出ていないので）

以下の例では変数の宣言ですが、関数、マクロ、コメントで２行空白を入れたいです。

```
int i;


int j;
```

現在のclang-formatの設定は下記の通りです。

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 4
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
IndentCaseLabels: false
ColumnLimit: 0
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse
AfterControlStatement: false
SortIncludes: Never
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: true

MaxEmptyLinesToKeep 2
```

**23/02/02 追記1**
希望の動作は、`MaxEmptyLinesToKeep 2` を設定した動作を希望していますが
設定しても反映されませんでした。
`OverEmptyLines: 2` も設定してみましたが、反映されませんでした。

**23/02/02 追記2**
フォーマット前、後、希望する動作を追記しました。

フォーマット前（変数 i と j の宣言の間に空白の改行が2行あります）

```
int i;


int j;
```

フォーマット後（空白の改行が１行削除されます）

```
int i;

int j;
```

希望する動作（フォーマットしても改行を２行保ってほしいです。）

```
int i;


int j;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode は使用していないのでキーワードで少し調べた程度ですが、Clang-Format の `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep` に関する説明を読む限り "保持する連続空行の最大数" のようです。

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#maxemptylinestokeep

> The maximum number of consecutive empty lines to keep.

ここでは例として `2` とすると、あくまで 2行以上の空行は 2行になるように整形するけど、逆に 2未満の場合 = 1行だけの空行に対しては何もしない、のような気がします。("常に2行の空行にする" では無い)

関連しそうなオプションとしては `OverEmptyLines` があるようです。

Comment: 質問と、例がわかりにくくすみません。
やりたいことは、 `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep` の動作で問題ないです。

ご教示いただいて、OverEmptyLines を試すために、サンプルの通り

AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Always
  OverEmptyLines: 2

と記述してみましたが、エラーが出てしまいました。

OverEmptyLines: 2

を単独で記述してみたところ、エラーは出ませんでしたが
変化はありませんでした。

Comment: VSCodeを再インストールしたら、'MaxEmptyLinesToKeep' の設定が効くようになりました。ありがとうございました。